# Typescript Reflect.getMetadata('design:type'..) returns Object instead of Date if the Angular 2 Stack is used

Tags: angular, typescript, reflect-metadata

The following code Sample is working as expected and prints out "[Function: Date]"

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
function logType(target : any, key : string) {
     var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
     console.log(`${key} type: ${t.name}`);
   }
export class Demo {
  @logType // apply property decorator
  test: Date;
}
let demo = new Demo();
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', demo, "test"));
```

If I place the same code within an Angular 2 Project, "function Object() { [native code] }" is returned.

I prepared a Plunker for this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/DhXT89U0q5fCOWlCrx6w?p=preview

Reflect.getMetadata('design:type' ...) is still working for custom classes and other builtin classes. I could only produce this problem with Date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem however not using Angular. In my case the TypeScript loader (ts-loader) transpileOnly setting was affecting the output. With the setting enabled it would cause the return type to be Object instead of Date.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the function, and not just.. put it there :), you should add parentheses after `@logType`

```
export class Demo {
  @logType() // add parentheses 
  test: Date;
}
```

On the other hand you should change your `@logType` function to something like this:

```
function logType(type: any) {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {  
     Reflect.defineMetadata('design:type', type, target, propertyKey);
  }
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
export class Demo {
  @logType(Date) // apply property decorator
  test: Date;
}
```

I've updated the plnkr to show what I mean:
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mccZldyfC6HLIxXXXzC5?p=preview)

You can only get either `string`, `boolean`, `number` or `object` with the built-in types. Where `object` will be anything, from `Date` to `Array` to your `Math` and `WeakMap`. All built-ins will evaluate to `Object`, I'm not sure if this a bug, or by design.

You can however use your method to get custom classes. If you would do

```
export class Demo {
  @logType
  test: Demo;
}
```

It will print out `Demo`

Comment: The decorator doesn't need (), in fact the typescript compiler would throw an error if one does so. The function also gets called (just have a look in the console of the plunker)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to get the type using just the `@logType` without actually passing in the type. I've updated my answer to get what you want. But i could be wrong, it has been a while since I've done research on decorators, and the spec could have changed

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I will try to use this as a workaround. Normaly the emitDecoratorMetadata compiler option should handle this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html . I'm still thinking it must be something else, as its working as expected without angular 2

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit more to explain it a bit better :)