# Typescript Reflect.getMetadata design:type returns Object instead of Date without angular testbed

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection, reflect-metadata

I want to start by saying it is **not** a duplicate of [Typescript Reflect.getMetadata('design:type'..) returns Object instead of Date if the Angular 2 Stack is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715864/typescript-reflect-getmetadatadesigntype-returns-object-instead-of-date-i) but is similar.

The following code:

```
import {} from 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

function test(target: any, key: string) {
    console.log(key, Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', target, key).name);
}

class Class { }

class Test {
    @test item: String;
    @test date: Date;
    @test instance: Class;
}
```

if ran with `ts-mocha test.ts` outputs

```
item Object
date Object
instance Class
```

while if ran with `karma start` that is set up as a part of the angular2 projects outputs

```
item String
date Date
instance Class
```

Why is that and how to make the test results consistent?

https://gitlab.com/sQu1rr/test-ts-date-reflect/tree/master (karma configuration is extracted from an angular2 project and is not cleaned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can fix one bug,but another one I don't know how to fixed,because I can't found the primitive type for such type.because type is only exists in typescript,in javascript there is no type.the type of String is not reference to javascript String class,if you want let typescript compile correctly you must use `string` in type sides.like `foo:string` nor `foo:String`;when you write `let string: String = String;` the compiler report errors,because left side ref a type,the right side ref a String constructor,they are different.I'm sorry,I'm not good english,so I wish you could understand what I was said.unimaginable,the typescript compiler will compile the String type into String class into .js file,you can use `tsc` compile the js file and see result.the 3rd test could be run,I think user defined class play the two roles:`the instance of the class` & `the type of the class`.but `Date` & `String` separate `type`/`constructor function`into two parts: `type` as an interface 'String',`constructor function` via global variable `StringConstructor`

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

function Test(expectedType: any) {
    return function (target: any, key: string): void {
        let type = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('design:type', target, key);
        test(`${target.constructor.name} ${key}'s type should be ${expectedType.name} but was ${type.name}!`, () => {
            expect(type).toBe(expectedType);
        });
    }
}

class TestClass {
}

class ReflectMetadataTest {
    @Test(String) item: string;
    @Test(Date) date: Date;
    @Test(TestClass) instance: TestClass;
}


test('metadata', () => {
    let type = String;
    let clazz = ReflectMetadataTest.prototype;
    let decorator: any = Reflect.metadata("foo", type);
    decorator(clazz, 'item', void 0);

    expect(Reflect.getMetadata('foo', clazz, 'item')).toBe(type);
});
```

### Maybe the two tests below could answer your question

the `Date` & `String` are legacy system.they define class via function nor class declarations,so typescript can't fetch the type information.then typescript pass the `Object` type if you run typescript in memory,however,when the `tsc` compile .ts into .js,it preserve  the `type` as same as the `constructor function` .the test below is let's say the function `Foo` is a function based class,the typescript can't infer the `Foo` type so it emit an `Object` to Reflect.metadata(),but when you compile the test file in to .js via `tsc`,the compiler will preserve the `type` to `constructor function`.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

function Test(expectedType: any) {
    return function (target: any, key: string): void {
        let type = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('design:type', target, key);
        test(`${target.constructor.name} ${key}'s type should be ${expectedType.name} but was ${type.name}!`, () => {
            expect(type).toBe(expectedType);
        });
    }
}


function Foo() {

}
interface Foo {
}


class ReflectMetadataTest {
    @Test(Foo/*ref function*/) foo: Foo/*ref interface*/;
}

test('metadata', () => {
    let type = Foo;
    let clazz = ReflectMetadataTest.prototype;
    let decorator: any = Reflect.metadata("foo", type);
    decorator(clazz, 'item', void 0);

    expect(Reflect.getMetadata('foo', clazz, 'item')).toBe(type);
});
```

### Summary

if you want make the metadata work correctly in both .js and .ts you must define `a wrapper class`/`a subclass` with `legacy function based class`.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

function Test(expectedType: any, same: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, key: string): void {
        let declaredType = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('design:type', target, key);

        test(`${target.constructor.name} ${key}'s type should ${same ? '' : 'not '}be \`${expectedType.name}\` & declared type was \`${declaredType.name}\`!`, () => {
            expect(declaredType == expectedType).toBe(same);
        });
    }
}


function Foo() {

}
interface Foo {
}
class MyDate extends Date{

}
class ReflectMetadataTest {
    // this test always false even if you compile .ts it into .js file
    @Test(Foo/*ref function*/, false) foo: Foo/*ref interface*/;

    //this test is true when you compile .ts it into .js file
    @Test(Date, false) date: Date;
    @Test(String, false) String: String;
    @Test(Number, false) Number: Number;

    //this test is always true both in .ts & .js
    @Test(Number, true) number: number;
    @Test(Boolean, true) boolean: boolean;
    @Test(String, true) string: string;
    @Test(MyDate, true) myDate: MyDate;
    @Test(ReflectMetadataTest, true) test: ReflectMetadataTest;
}
```

Comment: That partially explains why it **shouldn't** work on built-in types and how to solve the String issue. That doesn't explain, why Date is correctly identified when I run tests in angular2 testbed using karma+phantomjs...

Comment: the `Date` is the same problem.because typescript can't describe the Date type in memory so it pass the `Object` to the decorator nor the `Date`,this may be a bug of typescript?but user defined class combine two parts `type`&`class` so the compiler can pass it correctly in memory.

Comment: OK so are you saying that in karma/phantomjs Date is passed instead of Object to decorator because the classes are redefined somewhere? My questions is about why does it **work** when I use karma/phantomjs?

Comment: because `ts-mocha` not compile it into js,it run your tests directly in memory.the other one compile .ts into .js may be via `webpack`/`babel`.

Comment: I have updated my answer,the second tests would be helped you.

Comment: if you find some solution solve the `date` type,please tell me.thanks.

Comment: I think I could answer your question,the `Date` & `String` are legacy system.they define class via function nor class declarations,so typescript can't fetch the type information.then typescript pass the `Object` type if you run typescript in memory,however,when the `tsc` compile .ts into .js,it preserve  the `type` as same as the `constructor function` .